# iOS 5 Partial Transitioning View Controllers

Tags: ios5

I am having trouble to find out the best way of transitioning only a part of view controller.
This is what I have:
In my first view controller, I have a UIView that acts like a header where I provide some ImageViews and Labels, bellow it I have a table view.
When user clicks a cell from the table, another view controller is pushed and it contains the same UIView header as before and bellow it some detailed information about the cell item selected.

This is what I want:
Since both view controllers have the same UIView header, I would like it to be fixed and only change the bottom contents (table view or detailed informations). I expect a transitioning effect that only move the contents on the bottom.

I appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

A View controller controls views, so it isn't a case of transitioning view controllers, you can do this by transitioning views.

You can have multiple views. that occupy portions of the window.

In your case you could keep the top view (the one that you call the header) and when you need to change a part of the view your controller just needs to create a new view to display and then you can animate it into it's new position on top of the old view.

[UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW108) animations let you accomplish this. For example, you could use `transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:` to animate from your table view to the detail view.

It is possible to have a different view controller for this detail view if you want. All you need to do is create the view controller with the information that is needed to configure its view, and then pass this view as the `toView` to the above method, and then when you are done with the view, you can use the same method to transition back to the original tableview.

Comment: I understand your suggestion, but also, I would like the back button in navigation controller to be showed when the second view is displayed. Thats why I use two view controllers managed by a navigation controller.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Do you want a top level navigation controller or do you want your subview in a navigation controller?

Comment: A top level navigation controller.

Comment: So you want to change a part of the current view but make it look like the whole view is in a Navigation controller. And when you click on the back button, only the subview changes?

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much it! :)

Comment: Any idea how I can achieve it?